# How do I change the default start folder of jupyter-notebook?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed anaconda on `C:\Users\My_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2`, the issue is that whenever I launch jupyternotebook or any other from the anaconda navigator the starting directory is a external network location Z:. I want jupyter to be installed and run on C:\ how do I solve it?

Here is a copy of the anaconda command prompt so you better understand what I mean.

[image: This is a copy of the anaconda command prompt so you better understand what I mean]

I have already reinstalled anaconda making sure that I select the C:\ directory, even installing offline so the computer has no acces to Z:, but the result is the same. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined a new windows PATH variable to ~\Anaconda2\Scripts. Then I can start jupyter notebook anywhere just by tiping "jupyter notebook" on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS, edit this file:

```
/Users/{your user name}/anaconda/bin/jupyter_mac.command
```

Original was:

```
DIR=$(dirname $0)<br/>
$DIR/jupyter-notebook
```

I added a line:

```
DIR=$(dirname $0)<br/>
cd /Users/{your user name}/{whatever folder you want}/<br/>
$DIR/jupyter-notebook
```

This way, Jupyter notebook starts directory you want. Be careful about folder names with space. Use **\** before the space. For example, the Google Drive folder shoule be:

```
cd /Users/{your user name}/Google\ Drive/
```